# How to send a string to default system printer in Clojure

Tags: java, clojure

First of all I am new to Clojure. I was wondering how  to print a string to a printer. As I understand it I need to use Java interop. I searched for Java code and found these lines of code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.print.*;

public class foo implements Printable {
  private static Font sFont = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN , 64);

  public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat Pf, int pageIndex)
      throws PrinterException {
    if (pageIndex > 0) return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2.setFont(sFont);
    g2.setPaint(Color.black);
    g2.drawString("Save a tree!", 96, 144);
    return PAGE_EXISTS;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob( );
    job.setPrintable(new foo( ));
    if (job.printDialog( )) {
      try {
        job.print( );
      }
      catch (PrinterException e) {}
    }
    System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

I understand that I need to load the `Printable` interface with `proxy` and
after that to create a `PrinterJob` and set it printable, but I get confused
when I try to translate this to Clojure.
My attempt so far is this:

```
    (ns controller.core
      (:gen-class)
      (:require [clj-http.client :as client]
                [cheshire.core :refer :all]
                [clojure.edn :as edn]
                [clojure.java.io :as io]
                [clojure.string :as str]
)
      (:import [java.awt.print PrinterJob Printable PrinterException]
               [java.awt Graphics2D Color]      
               )
      )
    (defn make-page []
      (proxy [Printable] []
        (print
          [graphics page-format page-index]
          (if (> page-index 0)
            Printable/NO_SUCH_PAGE
            (let [g2 graphics]
              (.drawstring g2 ("foooooooo" 96 144))
              Printable/PAGE_EXISTS

          ))
      )

    (defn prnt []
      (let [print-j (PrinterJob/getPrinterJob)]
        (.setPrintable print-j (make-page))
        (.print print-j)))

    (defn -main
      [& args]
      (prnt)
      )
```

Also in the first sample code when the Graphics class is passed to Graphics2D how to translate that to clojure and why is happening, I mean can I just pass the graphics? Also if I don't set the Color class and Font will they be some default values? If anyone could explain I would be gratefull!

Answer (score 0):

Clojure does nothing special to set Color or Font by default. I am not familiar with  AWT, but it could be possible that you see nothing because Color/Font defaults are incorrect? You could define the font in the namespace, i.e

```
(def sfont (Font. "Serif" Font.Plain 64)
```

which you can reference from inside `make-page`.

Alternatively, you could use `reify` to define the font anonymously, like so:

```
(defn make-page []
  (let [sfont (.Font "Serif", Font.PLAIN , 64)]
    (reify Printable
      (print [graphics page-format page-index]
        ;; .. rest of code 
        ))))
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response! I have tried it but with no luck. I think I am missing something in the Java interop, caused from the poor knowledge of Java. :/